# Фото/видео Галерея

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

С помощью какой галереи лучше всего реализовать данную задачу?
Показывается главное фото, снизу миниатюры + стрелки для переключения фото.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сайт на чистом HTML
В отдельной вкладке так же есть видеогалерея.

Comment: С помощью любой подходящей из гугла. Я реализую с помощью slick slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лично я использую FlexSlider. Вот ссылка: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: FlexSlider полностью решил проблему. Благодарю